# RegEx with two separator and field extraction

Tags: logging

I'm trying to isolate the **second field**, comma-separated, in an already regex-ed sub-string. My source string is something like:

Info: 10.10.10.10 "TryingToIsolate" - [14/Mar/2016:15:44:00 +0100] "GET http://www.google.com" 200 12 £GG_sear,**44**,3,"-",-,-,-,1,"-",-,-,-,"-",1,-,"-","-",-,-,GG_sear,-,"-","-","Unknown","Unknown","-","-",234,0,-,"-","-",-,"-",-,-,"-","-"£ - "None-Default-None-Default-None"

and I would like to get the vaule **44** within the £ symbols.
I can get easily whatever is within the "££" by using:

\£(.*)\£

but whatever I try for taking out the second field it doesn't work properly.

Comment: what is your input string from which you are trying to extract ? also I cannot see <> in your example

Comment: Apologies, I meant:

"...and I would like to get the vaule 44 between the "£" characters. I can get easily whatever is within the "££" by using:

\£(.*)\£

but whatever I try for taking out the second field it doesn't work properly.

I apprecciate any help..."

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it is going to be numeric only, then you can catch it with the regex

```
£\w+,(\d+),.*£
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eK2zX6/1)